# Sporadic JS Bug Chasing: Too Much Recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I am hesitant to ask yet another "too much recursion" question, but I'm totally lost for ideas.

I am getting a "too much recursion" error during my .ready(), which is unhelpfully occurring:

- Very sporadically (ie once a month) for me
- Pretty much every other time I have to do a demo using someone else's computer (of course)
- On FF, Chrome, IE9 etc, on our dev, prod and test systems

And it's getting trapped deep inside the bowels of jQuery (1.10.2). Specifically, at [this line of Sizzle](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L836), inside Sizzle.attr.

I've tried to "force" this bug to appear by using low memory VMs, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm stumped as to how to find where this is occurring, since I can't get a stack trace. I've got no minimal example either, since I can't make the bug happen.

The most likely candidate is something like triggering an event inside its handler, but I can't see how that would occur only sometimes, on load?

**How can I try and find what is happening?**

Any help or tips or links most welcome. If it's useful, I'm using jQuery, jQuery UI, and OpenLayers.

Comment: Are you sure this is a jQuery problem and not your own code? What lead you to that line as the culprit? Can you share your code?

Comment: @elclanrs No, I don't think it's a jQuery bug at all. I think they're probably a lot better about testing than I am :). I think the bug probably *is* in my code, but since I can't reliably trigger the bug I can't make an example, or a stack trace, and you probably don't want to see the 2000+ lines of javascript where it 'could' be. Perhaps I didn't word my question well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking at a JS stacktrace when it errors to see the call chain - for a recursion problem this should show you what's recursing. You can see this with dev tools in the browser, for example in Firefox use Firebug's 'script' tab and use the 'stack' output tab.

Just noticed you'd said you'd tried to get a stack trace. Try putting a breakpoint at the line you know is bad and looking at the stacktrace to see if/when it seems to be recursing into some function above that line.

Comment: If I could make the bug happen, this is exactly what I'd do. But I can't. It's only happening sometimes, and not at all when I've tried to trigger it.

Comment: Did you see my 2nd paragraph I edited in? Can you try and break on that line and look in the trace for potential recursion?

Comment: I'm not sure if it solved it. It certainly helped, and I've made some changes to avoid calling that part of jQuery that way. This bug seems to be like a nasty cold: it goes away and then comes back.